# If I'm storing music and movies in iTunes, does it free up space on my Mac?

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, storage

My Macbook has 250 GB hard drive but I'm at 220 GB of movies and music. If I transfer those files from my Mac to iTunes will if free up space on my Mac?

Comment: iTunes or iTunes Match?

Answer (score 3):

No, placing files in iTunes doesn't reduce the space required on the Mac. The files are still stored on your Mac.

Comment: In fact, if you have 'Keep iTunes Media folder organised' and 'Copy files to iTunes Media folder…' both on you could be doubling up the number of music files without realising.